# Unauthorized Column Operation in GridDB

Tags: griddb

### Unauthorized Column Operation in GridDB

I was attempting to write a TQL query in GridDB to add the `retweets` and `favorites` columns together within the `sum()` function to calculate the total engagement for each hour, which is shown as follows:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('hour', created_at) as hour,
       sum(retweets + favorites) as engagement
FROM tweets
WHERE created_at >= '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY hour;
```

But I received the following error:

```
[Server]: 60100

[Description] (Unauthorized column operation)
```

Can anyone explain this error to me and how I could aggregate the `retweets` and `favorites` columns together?